# How to make gauge label stretch across full width of gauge panel?

Tags: ssrs

I have a gauge panel (grey) onto which I am trying to put a gauge label (green) that should stretch across the entire panel. However, when I put 100 into the Width property, it doesn't actually stretch across the entire panel -- see the sliver of grey on the right.

[image: gauge panel/label]

[image: properties for the gauge label (green)]

The documentation claims that "When parent elements have different width and height values, the size of the gauge element is calculated as a percentage of the smaller of the two values." However, this too is apparently false, as the height is 85% of the width in my panel, and the green background of my label clearly stretches more than 85% of the way across. I've also tried manually setting parent items, to no effect.

Is there something I'm doing wrong here, or is this the typical crappy SSRS bug?

Comment: I'm far from well versed in SSRS, but what version are you using and have you tried different browsers?

Comment: It's rendering within SSDT/Visual Studio rather than online, and it renders this way through the built-in preview as well as in PDFs and such. Version info -- Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Shell (Integrated) 14.0.23107.0 D14REL; SQL Server Data Tools 14.0.61705.170; SQL Server Reporting Services v14.0.608.142